# How to split a long text into multiple pieces/pages to fit into a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

While working on a `WinForm` application, I would like to split a long text (only characters, no images, no special format) into multiple pieces (pages), in order to fit them into a `RichTextBox`.

The problem is that `RichTextBox` doesn't support multiple pages.

I have to write my own algorithm (some kind of DP programming) to split the text.

Currently I am using `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` to check whether a string can fit into the rich textbox, for example:

```
bool canfit(String str)
{
    Size rbx_size = new Size(rbx.Width, rbx.Height);
    Size sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(str, rbx.font, rbx_size, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.GlyOverhangPadding)
    return (sz.Height < rbx_size.Height);
}
```

It doesn't work very well, because I think the function above is not accurate.

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: It would be super helpful if you could provide an example and your attempt thus far.

Comment: Please, *specify* page. Is it, say, `N` or less lines? At most `C` characters? Combination of the rules above?

Comment: the edit is not helpful

Comment: @zackraiyan also your comment.

Comment: @AhmedOsama I think zack's comment is having it's point and also helpful for OP and question editors that the question is still not helpful for people to understand what is basic requirement.

Comment: @AhmedOsama , the question was edit but the edit wasn't enough...now don't tell me i cant even SPELL THAT OUT

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I add some code example

Comment: Always add `TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl` when measuring a string that has to fit inside *any* WinForms container. However, what a *page* is, still not clear.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. Page means the string which can fit into the richtext box without the vertical scroll bar. If the string exceed the height of rich textbox, then we need to split it to multiple pages

Comment: So, you're building a sort of reader and you want to show single pages of a document (the lenght of which can't fit in the RichTextBox client area), without any visible scrollbar. What needs to be calculated is the position of the last character of each page, which will define the substring of the complete document. This can be solved with a combination of `GetLineFromCharIndex()` and `GetFirstCharIndexFromLine()`. If you want, I can post a sample code for this.

Comment: @Jimi, Yes. Sample code would be very helpful, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've posted a possible solution for your question. The complete source code for the RichTextBox editor can be downloaded from [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/7Q3Vgmi3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed problem, the way I've interpreted it, is to split the text of a source document in a number of substring (Pages), such as each substring can fit in a `RichTextBox` client area, without spawning/requiring the scrollbars.

Thus, the first task is to calculate the number of Chuncks/Pages into which a given Document has to be split.

The [TextRenderer Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer) methods are the usual tools.
The class must be instructed, while performing the calculation, to wrap the text (as the RichTextBox control will), exclude any padding and fit the string in a TextBox type control edit area.

The main [TextFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags) flags will then be:

```
TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl;
```

The next task is to calculate how many letters/symbols will fit in the client area of a RichTextBox control, so that no scroll bars are needed.

The `Winforms` `RichTextBox` control doesn't offer any specific tool, but the non-specific ones are enough to perform this calculation.

> As a note, the [Lines[] property][3] (derived from TextBoxBase)
> reports only the original text line splitting (intended as line
> feeds), not the lines generated by the internal word-wrapping.

However, the TextBoxBase [GetFirstCharIndexFromLine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.getfirstcharindexfromline) and [GetLineFromCharIndex()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getlinefromcharindex) can be used in combination to achieve the same result:
Knowing how many lines can fit in the ClientArea, the first character in the next line will be one character more than the last character of the last visible line in the ClientArea (spaces are not wrapped).
Then, repeat this procedure while there are enough lines to fill the ClientArea. The last *Page* will contain the reminder of `[Total Lines] / [Lines per Page]`.

A visual representation of the results of this procedure:

[image]

Sample code that performs the basic task of calculating the size and splitting the text of a source document. The complete source code used to create sample image: [(PasteBin - RTB Reader)](https://pastebin.com/7Q3Vgmi3)

```
string Document = "[SomeDocumentText]";
List<string> Pages = new List<string>();
TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.Top | TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | 
                        TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl;

Size textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText(Document, richTextBox1.Font, richTextBox1.ClientSize, flags);
int numberOfPages = textSize.Height / richTextBox1.ClientSize.Height;

if (textSize.Height > richTextBox1.Height) {
    richTextBox1.Text = Document;
    richTextBox1.Update();

    int firstCharOfLastShownLine = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0, richTextBox1.ClientSize.Height));
    int visibleLines = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstCharOfLastShownLine);
    int totalLines = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(richTextBox1.Text.Length - 1);

    for (int p = 0; p < numberOfPages; p++) {
        int firstLineOfPage = (p * visibleLines);
        int firstCharOfPage = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(firstLineOfPage);

        int firstLineOfNextPage = (p + 1) * visibleLines;
        firstLineOfNextPage = (firstLineOfNextPage > totalLines) ? totalLines : firstLineOfNextPage;
        int lastCharOfPage = (firstLineOfNextPage < totalLines)
                           ? richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(firstLineOfNextPage) - 1
                           : richTextBox1.Text.Length;
        Pages.Add(richTextBox1.Text.Substring(firstCharOfPage, lastCharOfPage - firstCharOfPage));
    }
}
else {
    Pages.Add(Document);
}
richTextBox1.Text = Pages.First();
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you!

Comment: There is a typo in the code "LastCharOfPage - FirstCharOfPage" should be "LastCharOfPage - FirstCharOfPage +1".
Besides that, It works pretty well, Thanks a bunch!.  Today I notice that if the document is very large, the UI will freeze. It seems that I cannot put the code in a worker thread, since most of the function is rely on richtextbox. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: @camino  Well, I think the heavy work (parsing the text) can be done in another thread. I'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Jimi, I split the large text into small chunks, then for each chunk call your function, and it works, Thanks so much for your help

Comment: @camino  Allright. Anyway, I've already written down a schema for a multithreaded reader. I'll post it here when it's ready.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure and I did not test the code but I hope it may help you, at least will give you an idea.

Convert your font size pt to px

```
Float points = 72; // each point in pixels 
Float fontSize = 12; // font size
Float dpi = 96; // find screen dpi (96 is very common I know)
Float px = fontsize * dpi / points; // each lines need px (exp: 16)
```

Find count of lines in your text (exp: 200 lines)

```
var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt").Length;
var lineCount = 0;
using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\file.txt"))
{
    while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

We found line count and how many pixel needs for each line at step 1 and 2, so we can find delimiter positions for mark the text in related line

```
Float totalTextPixels = lineCount * px;
Float textFieldHeight = 200; // for example
Float eachSplitLine = totalTextPixels / textFieldHeight;
```

loop lines again

```
var lineCount = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\file.txt").Length;
var lineCount = 0;
using (var reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\file.txt"))
{
    while (reader.ReadLine() != null)
    { 
        lineCount++;
        if(lineCount == eachSplitLine){
            // Put a deliminiter here (I don't know how)
            // for example | (pipe)
            lineCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and split your text with |

I know it is not robust and prof. solution, this is only an idea...

Have good days.

Comment: @camino you too